# LTspice problem with small amplitute sine wave

Tags: ltspice, sine

I simply wanted to generate a low amplitude sine wave, but the weird waveform happened. Why is the plot not showing the sine wave?

[image: some rectified-shape waveform]

Comment: A guess: your time step is too small and this is some weird aliasing.

Comment: Where is node n001?

Answer (score 2):

You can overcome numerical and graphical issues like this by using the following directive (which uses better floating point precision and doesn't discard simulation points from the graph):

```
.option plotwinsize=0 numdgt=16
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This thing had confused me for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate dc voltage source in series with the ac source works without using the option directive suggested by @devnull. Grounding the ac source allows the small voltage ac source to be simulated around 0V then added to the dc requiring less precision.
Of course the option directive is a good choice.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.